# Swift: How to declare view descendants

Tags: xcode, swift, autolayout

I'm trying to add the following constraint to align an image within a table cell. self refers to the UITableViewCell object within which the image view will reside:

```
    var imageViewTest = UIImageView();

    self.rowImageView = imageViewTest;

    var xAlignmentConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: imageViewTest,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX,
        relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
        toItem: self,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX,
        multiplier: 1,
        constant: 137
    );


NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([xAlignmentConstraint]);

self.addConstraint(xAlignmentConstraint);
```

When running the code, I get the following error:

> Unable to activate constraint with items because they have no common
>   ancestor.  Does the constraint reference items in different view
>   hierarchies?  That's illegal.

How do I declare imageViewTest to be a descendant of self?

Comment: When adding your own constraints the recommended practice is usually to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to false on the view you're adding the constraints to, besides whatever the issues here is.

Comment: Which method call generates the error, activateConstraints() or addConstraints()? Should you be adding it first?

Comment: The key was adding is as a subview via self.addSubview(self.rowImageView). Also I did have to set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false) in order to set my own dynamic constraints on the subview

Comment: The Apple Docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AdoptingAutoLayout/AdoptingAutoLayout.html  suggest it. Look at the 2nd paragraph below the first illustration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `rowImageView` as a subview of self.

```
var imageViewTest = UIImageView()
self.rowImageView = imageViewTest
self.addSubview(self.rowImageView)
```